# moving index.html to parent folder apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm moving my (Drupal)site's index.html from within a demo folder to its parent folder "htdocs" like so. But other script files and css files remain in the same demo folder.

Before:

1. data/apache2/**htdocs/demo/index.html**
2. data/apache2/htdocs/demo/script.js
3. data/apache2/htdocs/demo/style.css

After:

1. data/apache2/**htdocs/index.html**
2. data/apache2/htdocs/demo/script.js
3. data/apache2/htdocs/demo/style.css

> I'm not sure of the changes that need to go into the httpd.conf or
>   .htaccess file to make this move of index.html to its parent folder to
>   work. At the same time, the new rule or alias should look for other
>   resources(js,css) in the demo folder.

httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/data/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess --> present under data/apache2/htdocs folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteBase /

  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
     RewriteRule ^ /

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The demo folder does not have .htaccess file.

Comment: ok, i have changed the rewriterule so as to avoid the 500 error, edited above rule as well.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ /` is not required and will still produce 500 error

Comment: That is my current rule, I would want to know based on the movement of folder structure what is the expected rule or condition or alias etc..